# Why flyway doesnt support reset?

Tags: java, maven, flyway

As the title says, why flyway doesn't support reset or is there a way to do it? It is more helpful during development.

Right now i have to write shell script to do that in which I have to handle the profiles(test/dev) in shell script. I like to know is there a nice way to do that?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by reset

Comment: Drop create migrate.

Answer (score 0):

flyway clean migrate

Should do the trick

Comment: But I am using the flyway from maven.

Comment: Then it's mvn flyway:clean flyway:migrate